# How long would it have taken to sail from Boston to Nova Scotia in 1775?

Tags: boston

I have to write a diary for my Social Studies class on what life as a loyalist was like.  How long would it have taken them to sail from Boston to Nova Scotia, also known as British North America in about 1775?

Comment: If you're the same Olivia as the one [discussed here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/can-the-mods-email-a-possibly-disgruntled-user?cb=1), be sure to read that thread, because by merging your accounts you'd have a lot more rep.

Comment: Boston to Halifax 2 days? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marblehead_to_Halifax_Ocean_Race) says 30-45 hrs.

Comment: Quick comment - this question is a _good_ example of how to ask a homework question.   The question is specific and answerable. +1

Answer (score 6):

**Probably about 3 to 4 days, but less than 3 days would have been possible in very favourable conditions. However, one might have to wait several days for suitable sailing conditions.**

This is a difficult question to answer as there are [a lot of variables](http://americanpatriotseries.blogspot.com/2013/06/18th-century-travel-speeds-by-ship.html), not least type of ship, seamanship, cargo carried, wind speed and direction, and time of year.

That said, [sailing speeds](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/109720/1/786607629.pdf) from around 1750 to 1780 averaged 4.5 to 5 knots, but in favourable winds it could be much faster. This would mean a [sailing time](http://ports.com/sea-route/port-of-halifax,canada/port-of-boston,united-states/#/?a=682&b=1559&c=Port%20of%20Boston,%20United%20States&d=Port%20of%20Halifax,%20Canada) of three and a half to four days, but 7 knots or more would have been feasible in very favourable conditions, thereby cutting the journey time to less than three days.

One actual voyage in March 1776 took 3 to 4 days. [On the 17th of March, 1776](https://historyofmassachusetts.org/what-forced-british-leave-boston/), General Howe and the British evacuated Boston for Halifax, Nova Scotia, having had to wait for favourable winds. However, they did not actually [set sail for Nova Scotia until the 27th of March](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/1776.html?id=uu1mC6zWNTwC&redir_esc=y), and they arrived at Halifax on the [30th of March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Halifax_(former_city)). As *Tomas By* implies in his comment, some ships in this fleet would probably have been able to go faster.

---

Other source:

*F. Singleton, [The Beaufort scale of winds – its relevance, and its use by sailors](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/wea.153)*

Comment: A single ship might travel faster than a fleet of 120.